# neovim onedark colortheme displaying wrong

Tags: neovim

I have recently downloaded neovim to start developing there, and I wanted a color theme the one dark from atom, but for some reason doesn't work properly, the whole screen comes blue, I searched in other places but I didn't see anyone with the same problem, I'm in macOS 12.5.1, I even tried to run the theme in a ubuntu machine, in a docker container and is the same problem, Has anyone had this same problem?

Here's a picture

screenshot of neovim

[image: 1]

Comment: Which plugin did you use for the theme?

Comment: I would recommend posting your config files on github then link the repo to here. It is difficult to pinpoint the issue without seeing your configs

Comment: https://github.com/Ethanol48/dotfiles this are my dotfiles for oh-my-zsh, what do you mean exactly with the config files? you mean the ~/.config directory?

Comment: about the plugin I used two different ones, both the same theme with little difference navarasu/onedark.nvim, and ful1e5/onedark.nvim

Comment: but it got the same result for both of them

Comment: I don't have any setting for changing the colors in my terminal, I just downloaded Iterm the emulator and it works, but I don't really like this terminal is slower

Comment: I just found this post that it seems that had the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49408010/neovim-display-issue-on-mac-os-x and tells to "set notermguicolors in your config." Does some one how to set it in the config? I can figure it out

Answer (score 0):

There's no solution I was using the default mac Terminal, it appears that the Terminal is stuck in the 1970's and doesn't process termguicolors, as a remedy.

I'm using alacritty know, and works fine know.